# Android заменить в теме основной цвет подсветки TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-edittext, material-design, android-themes

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно заменить основной свет подсветки в теме?

Использую такую разметку, для эффекта с подсказкой:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
           <EditText
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:id="@+id/editStreet"
               android:hint="Улица (без города)" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

На скриншетах видно какой эффект это дает.

Хочу заменить стандартный бирюзовый цвет как hint текста так и подчеркивание EditText. 
Знаю как заменить с помощью Patch 9, но только подчеркивание. Возможно существует просто свойство в теме, которое можно изменить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD:** Как заменить цвет подсказки нашел. Возможно ли заменить основной цвет фокуса на EditText без Patch 9 ?

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout" />

    <style name="TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout"    parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
                <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_dark</item>
                <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В целом все оказалось достаточно просто. В стиле прописываем:

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">#c5c5c5</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/accent</item>
```